# svg text positioning, overlapping or two styles for same text element

Tags: text, svg, alignment, overlap

I have two different svg text elements aligned horizontally one from the other:

[image]

"Title1", "20%" and "120.000" are three independent svg objects.The 120.000 text element is end anchored and the 20% is middle anchored.

What I am trying to do is to place the 20% text as it appears on the image but always setting the same space between it and the 120.000 text. Currently the position of the percentage is set like this:

```
canvas.append("text")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width/2) - width/4) + " ," + (height/2 - 10) + ")")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(function(d) { return data.values[0].percent});
```

Where "width" and "height" is the total width and height of the svg element that holds the pieChart

The problem comes when the right value text is too big: the percentage text overlaps:

[image]

I would like to place the two pieces of text in the same text element but the two pieces of text have different styles.

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

The two solutions that I've thought of are

- to be able to set two different styles to two parts of the same text element
- some way (that I don't know) to calculate the exact space that is occupied by the text on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Use a a single `<text>` element with two `<tspan>` children so you can individually style the different `<tspan>` elements.